# SCP Error Message "Operation not supported"

Tags: macos, unix, scp

I was recently stuck for too long on a rookie problem. I tried to use `scp` to copy over a directory of files to my local machine by executing the following command:

```
scp -r myUserName@myhost.mydomain.com:/data/jenkins/workspace/myproject/myFolder/ /home/myUserName/myFolder
```

However, executing this command (and several variants of it) resulted in the following error message:

```
/home/myUserName: Operation not supported
```

I did some research for my error message on Google and the StackExchange network but found only red herrings. As such, I thought that it might be useful for future noobs like me if I documented my problem and solution here.

**Edit**: To assist future viewers, debug info below:

```
scp -rv myUserName@myhost.mydomain.com:/data/jenkins/workspace/myproject/myFolder/ /home/myUserName/myFolder

...

debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to myhost.mydomain.com ([123.456.789.0]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -f /data/jenkins/workspace/myproject/myFolder/
Entering directory: D0755 0 myFolder
Sink: D0755 0 intTest
/home/myUserName/: Operation not supported
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2484, received 3908 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 8549.3, received 13450.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: @fixer1234 I get your argument, but do you see merit in the argument that this might be something useful for people to use to debug that they might have a typo? This error message is indicative of a typo, even though the actual message doesn't suggest that. That's why I added the answer. Additionally, there don't appear many online resources out there that indicate that.

Comment: I retracted the close vote.  But it might be worth leaving your comments so people get the context.

Comment: Agreed. The edit you made makes my intent clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `/home/myUserName` it should have been `/Users/myUserName`. I was using `scp` on Mac to copy files from a Linux host, but I also got the same message running `scp` from the remote Linux host back to my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that there was a typo in the destination folder name.  I used the folder `/home/myUserName` when it should have been `/Users/myUserName`. The fact that the folder didn't exist was what prompted the error message.

One may have expected "no such file or directory" but I'm on Mac. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88805) which says:

> `/home` is used as a mount point for the automounter (see `/etc/auto_master` and `/etc/auto_home`), you can't create your own directories in there.

This fact is the root reason for the cryptic "operation not supported" error I got.

Comment: I used the folder `/home/myUserName` when it should have been `/Users/myUserName`. The fact that the folder didn't exist was what prompted the error message.

Comment: I just wanted to document both the problem and the solution because Google and SO et al really didn't show how `Operation not supported` could have anything to do with the folder not existing.

Comment: In 2 days, you'll be able to accept your own answer, which will help clarify that this is a self-answered question.

Comment: I have added the debug info to the question. Note that in the debug info, the error message occurred right after the command tried to access the folder. Good call!

Comment: I was creating a script with scp and the best way to avoid this error was to ```scp -r -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$3@$2:$1" $(pwd)``` Sending the files to the PWD.